# Аварийная остановка программы

Tags: linux, c, ubuntu, gcc

Решил написать небольшую программу-рисовалку с обработкой нажатия клавиш на Си

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <graphics.h>

int main() {
    int driver, mode;
    driver = DETECT;
    mode = 0;
    initgraph(&driver, &mode, " " );
    int x, y;
    x = 300;
    y = 300;
    int c;
    while (1) {
        setcolor(14);
        bar(x, y, x+10, y+10);
        c = getchar();
        if (c == 'w') y = y - 5;
        if (c == 's') y = y + 5;
        if (c == 'a') x = x - 5;
        if (c == 'd') x = x + 5;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

После 5 секунд работы программа крашается

```
> [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue [xcb] Most likely
> this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
> [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that. game: ../../src/xcb_io.c:259:
> poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
> Аварийный останов (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Компилирую на ubuntu с помощью gcc

Comment: Что за чудо-юдо компилятор, мимикрирующий под Борланд 1990 лохматого года рОзлива вы используете?

Comment: Я предполагаю, что дело тут не в компиляторе (TS же пишет - GCC), а в некоей загадочной библиотеке под названием "graphics", Судя по сообщениям об ошибках, она основана на библиотеке XCB.  Не зная ничего об этой библиотеке, ответить TS почему она не работает - достаточно затруднительно...

Comment: Если в бесконечном цикле рисовать прямоугольники, то их должно быть очень много!